# Cannot push object to array scope from assync success callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope, push

I have default array:

```
$scope.columns = [
                {
                    field :"id",
                    title : $translate.instant('ID'),
                    width : 250,
                    template: function(dataItem) {
                        switch (dataItem.id)
                        {
                            case null:
                                return "N/A";
                            default:
                                return dataItem.id;
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    field :"name",
                    title : $translate.instant('NAME'),
                    width: 250,
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            operator: "contains"
                        }
                    }
                }
     ];
```

And i would like to push a new item into this array in the success callback:

```
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // successful data retrieval
        console.log("request success, checking state");
        console.log(data);
        // sent status to global HTTP status service
        var jsonResponse = ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
        console.log("Status response is " + jsonResponse.result);
        // do something with data
        switch (jsonResponse.result) {
        case true:
            console.log(data);
            var newColumn =      {
                field :"TEST",
                title : $translate.instant('TEST'),
                width: "auto",
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                },
            };

            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.columns.push(newColumn);
            });

            break;
        case false:
            growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('LIST_LOADING_ERROR'), 'error', $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
            break;
        }
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        var jsonResponse = ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
        console.log("Processing error with status " + status);
        growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('PROCESSING_REQUEST_ERROR') + jsonResponse.message, 'error', $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
        // hide loading spinner
        kendo.ui.progress(gridView, false);
    });
```

I tried scope apply and timeout function but without luck, new value is never added into the new default scope.

Template is following:

```
{{columns}}
<div id="test_grid_wrapper" data-ng-controller="TestCtrl" ng-init="initData()"> 
    <div id="test_grid" ng-if="contentAvailable"  data-ng-controller="TestCtrl" ng-init="initGrid()" >

    </div>
</div>
```

How can i solve it please?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can you provide us with the HTML template where your $scope.columns is bound?

Comment: I just udpated question

Comment: In your template, I don't see where $scope.columns is used...

Comment: On the first line {{columns}}

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing:

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.columns.push(newColumn);
});
```

Comment: This is not working. I think that success callback and inner switch making scope.columns unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

I think concat() is for two arrays so here you want to do push().
Moreover, I'd access directly the array on the $scope:

```
$scope.columns.push(newColumn)
```

Also it might be linked to this problem: [Understanding scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)
Indeed, you should not use an object/array that is supposed to changed directly on the scope but should wrape it in another object:

```
$scope.myData = {
    columns: [
        {
            field :"id",
            title : $translate.instant('ID'),
            width : 250,
            template: function(dataItem) {
                switch (dataItem.id)
                {
                    case null:
                        return "N/A";
                    default:
                        return dataItem.id;
                }
            }
        },
        {
            field :"name",
            title : $translate.instant('NAME'),
            width: 250,
            filterable: {
                cell: {
                    operator: "contains"
                }
            }
        }
     ]
 };
```

and then use it like this:

```
{{myData.columns}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine without having to use `$scope.apply()`. When your async request comes back, simply do:

```
$scope.columns.push(newColumn);
```

This will automatically update your templates. I have included a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeGertrudes/HB7LU/10160/) to demonstrate.